# How do you set all JLabels made in a list to change what is shown

Tags: java, swing, list, jbutton, jlabel

**FIXED**

I'm sorry for the bad title, but I spend 5 minuits on it and can't phrase it better sorry.

I need to have it so that if you press JButton all, it takes the image in all2 and also puts that into JLabel label (made with a list)

I put the JLabel all2 above map() because if I didn't, "ImageIcon setAll can't be resolve". I didn't put JLabel label above map() because it messes up with the creation of the 100 JLables made with the list listofLabels. All that it would show was one sigle Label.[image]
[image]

```
public class mapMaker {

ArrayList<JLabel> listofLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>(100);
ImageIcon forest = new ImageIcon("resources/terrains/forest.jpg");
ImageIcon wood = new ImageIcon("resources/terrains/wood.jpg");

JFrame frame = new JFrame("D&D");
JLabel all2=new JLabel( wood);



public map() {
    int a=0,b=50;
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(100,0,1000,700);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    JButton all=new JButton("Set All To");
    frame.getContentPane().add(all);
    all.setBounds(600,450,150,50);
    all.setFont(new Font("Courior", Font.BOLD, 25));
    all.addActionListener(boardListener);

    frame.getContentPane().add(all2);
    all2.setBounds(800,450,50,50);
     all.addActionListener(boardListener);


for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    JLabel label =new JLabel(forest);    
    label.setIcon(forest);
        listofLabels.add(label);
        a=a+50;
        if(a>549) {
            b=b+50;
            a=50;
        }
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        label.setBounds(a, b, 50,50);
        label.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));


            }
}


ActionListener boardListener = new ActionListener (){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
ImageIcon setAll=(ImageIcon) all2.getIcon();

![enter image description here][2]label.setIcon(setAll);



    }
    };;

public static void main(String[]args) {
    new map();
}
```

}

Comment: I can't understand your problem based on your description. Why not have an array of JLabel, and simply iterate through the array setting all of the JLabel's Icons to the one selected?

Comment: put that as an answer and i'll up it

Comment: @Russell, There are so many things wrong with this piece of code (e.g. null layout manager, magic numbers, naming convention violations, lack of OOP design...).

Comment: this is because it was originally a longer code but i slashed it down quickly and cant figure out formatting on stackoverflow :)

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: when people tell me to fix my conventions, could they tell me a book or a website that goes over Java conventions!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply iterate through the array (or ArrayList) of JLabels setting all of the JLabel's Icons to the one selected?

For example:

```
ActionListener boardListener = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Set All To")) {
        ImageIcon setAll = (ImageIcon) all2.getIcon();
        for (JLabel label : listofLabels) {
           label.setIcon(setAll);
        }
     }
  }
};
```

Comment: button.setIcon(setAll) that almost fixes it but it says                                          Cannot invoke setIcon(ImageIcon) on the array type JButton[]

Comment: @Russell, "*iterate through the array*.."

Comment: I'm working on fixing that right now, but if you have any ideas, please comment

Comment: fixed it, just added  for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){

Comment: @Russell: see edit. Also if a change in your code does not work, then edit your question to show the code and post a comment alerting me of the change.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels  above all, very nice thread at all +1

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure is this what you expecting:

```
ActionListener boardListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Set All To")) {
          Icon setAllIcon = all2.getIcon();

          for (JLabel label : listofLabels)
            label.setIcon(setAllIcon);
        }
    }
};;
```

Edited as it is working fine as there is slight bug in the code mentioned:

Instead of this:

```
all.addActionListener(boardListener);

frame.getContentPane().add(all2);
all2.setBounds(800,450,50,50);
 all.addActionListener(boardListener);
```

Looks like you want to do:

```
all.addActionListener(boardListener);

frame.getContentPane().add(all2);
all2.setBounds(800,450,50,50);
all2.addActionListener(boardListener); // This is the changed line
```

Comment: that would be another way to do it yes, upping it because you didn't trash about my formatting :) (and because i think it works)